# Test an application GUI coded with Java Swing : best approach?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, testing

I have to automatically generate test for a Java "drawing" application GUI (like ArgoUML/LaTeXDraw/etc). I need to verify that the tested application behave correctly. In my given example, I need to check that the Undo/Redo buttons works well = Undo put the canvas in the predecessing state and Redo put it again in the state it used to be.

I have already an idea of how I will approach the problem but I would like feedback of experienced people:

- Should I use the Robot class to simulate the inputs onto the GUI? Or
  is there an easier way?
- I need to capture the state of the program for later analysis to see
  if the state of the program is consistent, should I just screenshot
  the window or is there a way to iterate through all the JFrame's
  components and capture their properties (it should include canvas
  state)?
- More importantly, I do not know how to locate each button on the
  interface. What is the simplest way to tell the Robot that a given
  button is at a certain (x, y) position in the window? Should I search
  the pixels in a .jpeg version of the button? Should I locate each
  button on the interface manually (i.e. create a class for each button
  containing x, y attributes)?
- And finally, I have never "attached" a Robot to a given program. Can
  I just load the .jar file of the software I want to test and tell
  Robot to operate on that window? Or do I need to work with all the
  source files from the original project?

Thank you for your time, if any part of my question seems not clear enough please tell me and I will try to explain it even more clearly.

P.S: any advice concerning the work I need to do is welcome :)

Comment: *"I have to automatically generate test for JAVA"* what is the benefit of such tests? Do theay really test behavior of the *code under test* or do they test that the test generator works correctly? I would not rely on such tests.

Comment: You could try to use ReTest (https://www.retest.de/en/), which comes with an interesting new approach to functional regression testing and ai-based monkey testing.

Comment: There are several versions of this question about -- I'm referring people to this [Open source tools for automation of Java GUI application testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/open-source-tools-for-automation-of-java-gui-application-testing) from now on.  It has good responses and I want to encourage _Thinking Q/A_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [done](https://github.com/bduby/ATM/tree/master/src/test/java) what you've [explained](https://github.com/bduby/ATM/blob/master/src/test/java/TestUtil.java) in the comment to the other answer.

`Robot` can be useful for various parts of the process but, depending on how it was written, the desire to follow best testing practices, and overall needs it can get limited quick. If you didn't write it or best coding practices keep you from getting access to or directly testing aspects of the application then other means are necessary.

My experience led me to tunnel down the main entry point using reflection to test the actual state (like text values of various components). `Robot` was only useful for my case to perform [key events](https://github.com/bduby/ATM/blob/master/src/test/java/TestUtil.java).

Ultimately, the answer(s) depend on many factors:

1. Robot? - Sure, use it as far as it suits your needs.
2. Do what's easiest while still meeting the requirements. If a screen shot will do, do it (with [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle))). If you need more information you can [get the components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) of a `JFrame` or `JPanel` and save what ever properties offered.
3. This can be done a number of ways though investigation of the UI. Finding the button and doing [`doClick`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick()) directly on it, moving the mouse with `Robot` and doing a mouse press, etc.
4. When you instantiate a new `Robot` it will be linked to the main device. Nothing more is needed in simple scenarios than `new Robot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

Given all that, there are pitfalls like focus. It's best to start your simulation/test and not touch *any* peripheral of the machine. Also, depending on the running time of some methods you may want to `Thread.sleep()` (as we regrettably did) or use joined threads.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, it is helping me quite a lot. But I still do not get your explaination for the 3rd question. When you used Robot how he knew that lets say the "New file" Button was at the position (340,220) on the JFrame ? You specified geometric coordinates for each button manually ? That's my biggest concern...

Comment: @LostReality, glad it's helping. It's been about a year since I worked on that so I'm not sure what you're referring to. I don't remember us using coordinates to get components and I scanned through the test suite and util code and didn't see anything like that. If we did do it somewhere it would have been through investigating the app code. Can you tell me the file and line number please?

Comment: @LostReality, if I misunderstood that last comment, we looked at the app source. So, we knew there's a `SimEnvelopeAcceptor` that extended `Button` in `Simulator.java`. Through reflection, we were able to get that button by variable name (`"envelopeAcceptor"`). If you don't have access to the app source it can still be done this way but you won't know the name so you'd have to get all of them and figure it out. At that point it could be best to use Robot's mouse movements and do a simulated click. That could be done through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add any code so I can just guess:

If your code follows the MV(V)C pattern you don't need to test though the GUI. You can directly test the controller methods that handle the redo/undo and verify that they correctly change the model and communicate with the undo/redo stack (is is part of the model in my world...).

Comment: The software I am willing to test was not coded by myself, the idea is really to generate a wide range of test cases then execute it onto the GUI. While the execution of those test the state of the GUI should be "recorded" to check if the app have the desired behavior. ie, you draw a rectangle in the canvas, then a circle, then Undo twice, then Redo = the canvas should contains a Rectangle.